# Invalid results based on MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb

Can anyone explain why the query below gives the result below? Does it have something to do with time zone and what is the best way to remedy this?

All I'm trying to do is get the records that fall on 10/2/2016.

```
> db.appointments.find({"appointment": {$gte: new Date("10/2/2016"), $lt: new Date("10/3/2016")}}).pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("580ee2a0a6f299d25aeceb42"),
    "appointment" : ISODate("2016-10-03T00:30:00Z")
}
```

Comment: Is this part of a function where you would otherwise be passing the dates? Have you tried passing them/using the same format? The "Z" at the end of the ISODate means you are using UTC time, using new Date() uses local time. Use new Date(Date.UTC(...)) if you want to also use UTC time during your query.

Comment: So why is it that if I `db.appointments.insert({ "appointment": new Date("10/2/2016 12:30"), "phoneNumber": "9168974578", "name": { "last": "Pyle", "first": "Gomer" }});` I get `"appointment" : ISODate("2016-10-02T19:30:00Z"),`?

Comment: Because without setting timezone, new Date(...) creates it in the local timezone, i.e. 1997-07-16T19:20:30+xx:xx rather than 1997-07-16T19:20:30Z. Check out [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/NOTE-datetime-19980827)

Comment: Here the timezone is unspecified, so it applies the local timezone offset before storing it as a UTC standard date in mongo.

Comment: So if I wanted to .find() it later how would I account for that?

Comment: You will have to search using a timestring with a specified timezone,. i.e. "2016-10-02T19:30:00Z", or "2016-10-02T12:30:00+xx:xx", where +xx:xx is the local timezone offset (+07:00 as it appears in this case).